# Javascript covering both string true and boolean true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following

```
$scope.user.infowindow.enable = ($scope.user.infowindow.enable=="true") ? true : false;
```

This checks if `$scope.user.infowindow.enable` is `"true"` and if it is then turns it to `true` else `false`

Sometimes `$scope.user.infowindow.enable` can be `true` and not a string, what would be the best what to write that into this script so that in the end `$scope.user.infowindow.enable` will be set as either `true` or `false` checking to see if its a string or not.

Thanks

Comment: A good reference: http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use or '||' statement

```
 $scope.user.infowindow.enable = ($scope.user.infowindow.enable==="true" || $scope.user.infowindow.enable===true) ? true : false;
```

Comment: what will happen when `$scope.user.infowindow.enable` is `"false"`

Comment: $scope.user.infowindow.enable will be false

Answer (score 0):

Or use "===", an explicitely treat different cases :

```
$scope.user.infowindow.enable = 
   ($scope.user.infowindow.enable === "true" || 
    $scope.user.infowindow.enable === true) ? true : false;
```

Though I would rather understand why a single value can "sometimes" be a String, and "sometimes" be a boolean. That's probably your real issue here...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$scope.user.infowindow.enable = (true === $scope.user.infowindow.enable || 'true' === $scope.user.infowindow.enable);
```